# How to delete from json table?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have a table like below:

```
                <table class="table">
                    <thead class="thead-dark">
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">ID</th>
                            <th scope="col">Nazwa</th>
                            <th scope="col">Cena</th>
                            <th scope="col">Kupujący</th>
                            <th scope="col"> </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php foreach($data as $key => $value): ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $value['id']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $value['name']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $value['price']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $value['buyer']; ?></td>
                            <td><button type="button" name="button2" >Usuń</button></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

how to delete item from this list via clicking on the button in last column of the table?

my php:

```
 
    $jsonData = file_get_contents("data.json");
    $data = json_decode($jsonData, true);
```

thanks for any help, I don't know how to get value by button clicking :/

Comment: you can pass `$key` on button click to php form and using `unset($data[$key])` on php you can remove particular record from array

Comment: @PrateikDarji can you show how to pass data on button click? :( I'm a newbie in php :(

Comment: Sure, I can you please explain me the flow where the data is loaded? the php and html code  are on same page?

Comment: yes, all is on this same page

Comment: i don't know how to get a key of the record in table to delete this row in php script

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your data is gotten from a file, so to get it done you need to go over all these steps in the same php script:

- Get data from this file
- Parse data with `json_decode`
- Remove an item using `unset($data['id'])`
- Save new data in the same file

Here is an example:

```php
$jsonData = file_get_contents("data.json");
  $data = json_decode($jsonData, true);

  // here we go
  if(isset($_POST['item_key']) && !empty($_POST['item_key'])) {
    $data = array_values($data);
    $i=0;
    foreach($data as $element) {
      //check if it's the right item
      if(intval($_POST['item_key']) == $element['id']){ // intval only if you are sure id passed in POST[item_key] always integer 
         unset($data[$i]);
      }
      $i++;
   }
    file_put_contents('data.json', json_encode(array_values($data)));
  }
```

`$_POST['item_key']` will come after submiting the form in the html, see below.
In your html code, you will need to add the following:

```html
<table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Nazwa</th>
            <th scope="col">Cena</th>
            <th scope="col">Kupujący</th>
            <th scope="col"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach($data as $key =>
        $value): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $value['id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $value['name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $value['price']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $value['buyer']; ?></td>
            <td>
                <!-- action="#" means you will stay in the same script after submit -->
                <form action="#" method="POST">
                    <input
                        hidden
                        type="text"
                        name="item_key"
                        value="<?php echo $value['id'];?>"
                    />
                    <input type="submit" value="Remove" />
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**UPDATE**

- Used `unset` with `array_values` after `json_decode`
- Removed `header(refre..)` since the refresh will be done by form submit to same script

Comment: i get an `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /24/table.php:1) in /24/table.php on line 56` after launch, line `56` is your `header("Refresh:0");`

Comment: and removing not work correctly :/ after click on button, item is still here

Comment: can you give me an example of your data.json?

Comment: ` [
 {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Cyberpunk 2077",
  "buyer": "V",
  "price": "199"
 }
]`

Comment: in this case, i will use `array_values` to get data after decode, will update you soon

Comment: Check also a full example here: https://github.com/mostafero/php-remove-html-table-item

Comment: `foreach($data as $i => $element) {` instead of managing the `$i` variable by yourself.